# Mathematica 10 crashes on copy/paste

Tags: front-end, version-10, crash

Mathematica 10 crashes in the following (simple) situation:

```
FormulaLookup["gas"]
```

This command will produce a long list of possible formulas.
Then I type the following command below the list (and not run it)

```
FormulaData[]
```

When I copy one of the formulas produced by the FormulaLookup command and paste it in the square brackets of the FormulaData command Mathematica crasches.

It happens only if the formula list is very long (as in looking for "gas") and not always but almost always.

Can someone check if that's a Mathematica bug or some specific problem with my machine?
(I'm on windows 8.1).

Comment: I could not replicate the result even when I copied the whole result from FormulaLookup into the square brackets for FormulaData. What did you try to copy/paste? Btw using "Gas" will give you more useful results.

Comment: I cannot not reproduce the crash under Win7 x64.

Comment: Thanks. Then it must be a problem with my system. Probably it's related to the fact that I didn't uninstall M9 and that some directories (BaseDirectory, UserBaseDirectory) are shared between the two versions.

Comment: I have been getting weird, inconsistent copy/paste crash behavior on MMA 10 Win 8.1 x64. It has been frequent enough to be fairly annoying so far. I also have v9 installed but I would be surprised if that were the problem.

Comment: We had a difficult time pinning down the cause of this crash.  This will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: I can confirm that I experienced this issue with V10 on Win 8.1.

Comment: So it seem it's a bug, at least for some systems. Actually it happened again on a notebook I was working on after trying to paste a small simple text string. Luckily I had just enabled NotebookAutoSave and so I haven't lost a couple hours work.

Comment: On V10.0.1 FormulaLookup["gas"] yields `Missing["NotAvailable"]` for me.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - try `FormulaLookup["gas laws"]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in Mathematica 10.0.0 and will be addressed in the first 10.0.x bug fix release (Mathematica 10.0.1). Thank you for reporting it and our apologies for any work lost because of this issue.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this was specific to a particular operating system? (in case we need to add that as a tag for the question)...